# how to override directive definitions in angular 2

Tags: angular

It is possible in angular 1 to decorate (override) directive definitions.

This is explained here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2926-overriding-directive-definitions-in-angularjs.htm

There is a builtin function

`angular.module( "X" ).decorator(`

for this.

In angular2 we don't have modules. The recommended way is to use typescript modules.

How will it be possible to decorate(override) directives in angular2?

The main reason i want to do this, is for customizations, when i deploy my app in a couple of sites.

Let's say that i have a bundle.js with all my app, I want then just to drop in a customer.js with a bunch of customizations, instead of changing and rebuilding my existing bundle.js for every site deployment.

Let's add a concrete example from the tour of heroes:
I defined my app component in a javascript file:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Hero} from './hero';
import {HeroDetailComponent} from './hero-detail.component';
import {HeroService} from './hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>My Heroes</h2>
    <ul class="heroes">
      <li *ngFor="#hero of heroes"
        [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
        (click)="onSelect(hero)">
        <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>
  `,

  directives: [HeroDetailComponent],
  providers: [HeroService]
})
```

I want to be able in another javascript file to switch the HeroDetailComponent with another component CustomHeroDetailComponent.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done something similar to dynamicaly load a custom module and configure the RouteConfig annotation for a POC. To import script file from a script, we need to use a dynamic module loader - Systemjs. Take a look at this [Lazy loading example](http://blog.mgechev.com/2015/09/30/lazy-loading-components-routes-services-router-angular-2)

To load component dynamicaly, you can use a virtual proxy as detailed in the example.

```
directives: [componentProxyFactory({'compName':'CustomHeroDetailComponent'})],
```

and for virtual Proxy -

```
export class ComponentProvider {
    compName:string;
}

export class ComponentDetail {
    path: string;
    name: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class DynamicComponentLoaderService
{
   //implement component lookup logic
    getComponentDetail(compName: string):ComponentDetail{
        return {'path':'./path/to/comp/custom.herodetail.component', 'name':'CustomHeroDetailComponent'};
    }    
}

export function componentProxyFactory(provider: ComponentProvider): Type {
    @Component({
        selector: 'component-proxy',
        template: `<span #content></span>`,
        providers: [provide(ComponentProvider, { useValue: provider})]
    })
    class VirtualComponent {
        constructor(el: ElementRef,loader:DynamicComponentLoader, inj:Injector, _service: DynamicComponentLoaderService, provider:ComponentProvider)
        {
            var compDetail = _service.getComponentDetail(provider.compName);
            System.import(compDetail.path)
                .then(m => {
                    loader.loadIntoLocation(m[compDetail.name], el, 'content');
                });
        }
    }
    return VirtualComponent;
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: i did look for a better solution but i guess it is it is the best available.

Comment: So far I couldn't find either. Will keep this post updated.

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct support for this AFAIK. 
I guess the underlaying issue is the same as https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5622

As a possible workaround, you can create a file that exports all your components and in the component source file you import from there;
Then you can change the bindings by replacing this exporting file.

It is ugly because all components start depending on that global file.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use following code.

```
    import {HeroDetailComponent} from './hero-detail.component';


        @Component({
          selector: 'custom-hero-detail',
          template:`
            <hero-detail param="...">
          `,
          directives: [HeroDetailComponent],
        })
        export class CustomHeroDetailComponent extends HeroDetailComponent{
          // custom code.
        }
```

You can extend the component and use that directive inside your.

Comment: How to extend from more than just one Directive? Will Angular Team implement this?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to override declarations (those you put in 'declarations' property for Module) in Angular during runtime.

To override a directive in runtime, you may put all the directive's logic into a separate injection token, inject it into directive and then dynamically provide a different token when needed.

Here is an example of a directive which may render the host asynchorounsly. Sometimes I need to escape this behavior and to render html synchronously, so I use AsyncRendererMock. You may look at '**@Inject(AsyncRenderer) private renderer: AbstractAsyncRenderer**'

```js
abstract class AbstractAsyncRenderer {
  protected templateRef!: TemplateRef<any>;
  protected viewContainer!: ViewContainerRef;
  protected zone!: NgZone;

  public init(templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, zone: NgZone) {
    this.templateRef = templateRef;
    this.viewContainer = viewContainer;
    this.zone = zone;

    return this;
  }
  public abstract render(renderFunction: () => void): void;
}

@Injectable()
export class AsyncRenderer extends AbstractAsyncRenderer {
  public render(renderFunction: () => void): void {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() =>
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        renderFunction();
      })
    );
  }
}

export class AsyncRendererMock extends AbstractAsyncRenderer {
  public render(renderFunction: () => void): void {
    renderFunction();
  }
}

@Directive({ selector: '[appAsyncRender]' })
export class AsyncRenderDirective {
  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private zone: NgZone,
    @Inject(AsyncRenderer) private renderer: AbstractAsyncRenderer
  ) {
    this.renderer
      .init(this.templateRef, this.viewContainer, this.zone)
      .render(() => this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef));
  }
}
```